# Unable to rotate footer in landscape

Tags: header-footer, longtable, landscape

[image]
I need my footer to remain at the bottom of the page in landscape form. Most entries say that `\usepackage{pdflscape}` should do that, but it doesn't seem to be working,

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\addtolength{\parskip}{\baselineskip}
\usepackage[margin=1in,includefoot]{geometry}
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\setlength{\parindent}{0.25in} 


%Tables preamble
\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[thinlines]{easytable}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{array, booktabs, makecell, multirow}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries\small}
\newcommand\mceight[1]{\multicolumn{8}{l}{#1}}
\newcommand\mctwelve[1]{\multicolumn{12}{c}{#1}}
\usepackage{arydshln}
\setlength\dashlinedash{0.2pt}
\setlength\dashlinegap{1.5pt}
\setlength\arrayrulewidth{0.3pt}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{afterpage}

\widowpenalty500
\clubpenalty=9996
\exhyphenpenalty=50 %for line-breaking at an explicit hyphen
\brokenpenalty=4991
\predisplaypenalty=10000
\postdisplaypenalty=1549
\displaywidowpenalty=1602
\floatingpenalty = 20000

\usepackage[labelfont=bf, textfont=bf]{caption}

% Header and footer
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyfoot[R]{ \thepage\ }
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{1pt}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{dcolumn} 

\begin{document}
 \afterpage{\clearpage}
 \begin{landscape}
\begin{longtable}[ht]{ l*{12}{S[table-format=2.3]}}
\caption{Quantile regresion results (pooled sample) for 2010-11}
\label{tab:quantile}                                                             \\
\toprule
\thead[b]{Dependant Variable:\\ log(hourly wages)}
    & \mctwelve{\thead{Percentiles}} \\
    \cmidrule(lr){1-1}\cmidrule(lr){2-13}      
\multirow{2}{*}{\thead{Independent\\ Variables}}
    & \multicolumn{2}{c}{10th}
        & \multicolumn{2}{c}{30th}
            & \multicolumn{2}{c}{50th}
                & \multicolumn{2}{c}{70th}
                    & \multicolumn{2}{c}{90th}
                        & \multicolumn{2}{c}{OLS}                   \\
\cmidrule(lr){2-3}\cmidrule(lr){4-5}\cmidrule(lr){6-7}
\cmidrule(lr){8-9}\cmidrule(lr){10-11}\cmidrule(lr){12-13}
    & {coeff} & {t-stat} & {coeff} & {t-stat} & {coeff} & {t-stat}
    & {coeff} & {t-stat} & {coeff} & {t-stat} & {coeff} & {t-stat}  \\
\hdashline                                                               \\
\endfirsthead

%%%%
\caption[]{Quantile regression results (contd.)}   
\endhead                                   
\toprule
\thead[b]{Dependant Variable:\\ log(hourly wages)}
    & \mctwelve{\thead{Percentiles}} \\
    \cmidrule(lr){1-1}\cmidrule(lr){2-13}      
\multirow{2}{*}{\thead{Independent\\ Variables}}
    & \multicolumn{2}{c}{10th}
        & \multicolumn{2}{c}{30th}
            & \multicolumn{2}{c}{50th}
                & \multicolumn{2}{c}{70th}
                    & \multicolumn{2}{c}{90th}
                        & \multicolumn{2}{c}{OLS}                   \\
\cmidrule(lr){2-3}\cmidrule(lr){4-5}\cmidrule(lr){6-7}
\cmidrule(lr){8-9}\cmidrule(lr){10-11}\cmidrule(lr){12-13}
    & {coeff} & {t-stat} & {coeff} & {t-stat} & {coeff} & {t-stat}
    & {coeff} & {t-stat} & {coeff} & {t-stat} & {coeff} & {t-stat}  \\
    \midrule                                                                \\
\endhead
\midrule
\multicolumn{12}{r}{\footnotesize\textit{Continued on the next page}}
\endfoot
\endlastfoot
%%%%      

\textbf{Constant}
    & 1.107   & 9.96     & 1.606   & 20.07    & 1.859   & 26.76 & 2.095   & 29.12    & 2.642   & 28.94    & 1.740   & 27.51     \\ \hdashline
\textbf{Gender}
    & 0.542   & 23.7     & 0.503   & 30.1     & 0.480   & 33.24 & 0.418   & 27.28    & 0.309   & 15.99    & 0.443   & 33.33     \\ \hdashline
 \bottomrule
    \label{tab:quantilereg} 
\end{longtable}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

Comment: why `\afterpage{\clearpage}` ? it is doing nothing at all if used before `\begin{landscape}` but `\afterpage` is a very fragile thing only intended to be used in very special circumstances.

Comment: what do you mean by "remain at the bottom"  ? with (pdf)lscape package the page head and foot are unaffected and stay at the bottom if the page is kept in portrait orientation, the body of the page (with the table) rotates.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I added an image to show the output. The footer also takes the landscape form, and I want it to stay in portrait form.

Comment: no what you show is the opposite: the footer does not change it is the standard page footer, just the body of the page not including the head and foot, is rotated.  That is the normal behaviour, imagine a book, even if the page content is rotated the page number should stay in the same place. (in any case I do not know of a package that rotates the page number along with the page content)